# iOS Not Invoking _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler on First Notification After App Termination in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, push

I'm working on a Flutter project where I use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to receive push notifications and display them in-app. Everything works as expected on Android. However, on iOS, I'm encountering a peculiar issue:

After the app is completely terminated (not in the background), the device receives the first push notification, and the app is woken up, but _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler does not get called. This issue only happens for the first notification received after the app has been completely closed. Subsequent notifications work fine and _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler is invoked as expected.

Here's a brief outline of my setup:

Flutter version: 3.3.1
firebase_core: ^1.24.0
firebase_analytics: ^9.3.8
firebase_messaging: ^13.1.0
firebase_crashlytics: ^2.9.0
I've confirmed that my payload from FCM is configured correctly, and the content-available flag is set to 1. My Info.plist is also configured with the necessary permissions for background fetch and notifications.

I'm wondering if there's a known issue or limitation with the first notification not triggering _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler on a completely terminated iOS app, or if there's any additional configuration I might be missing.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  debugPrint('[background msg]'); // didn't show
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'myProject',
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  debugPrint('[background msg]'); // didn't show
}
```

I saw that ios device get apns message in xcode console. but _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler doesn't get called during first push notification.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution.

move this code

```
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundMessageHandler);
```

to the front on the main method. That's all.

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11500